# C# Can't Access System Files even with administrator privileges

Tags: c#, system, privileges

My application needs to alter with some system files. (Like deleting Windows Event Logs from
"C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs" directory. (Somewhat same as Ccleaner does)

But i can't even see these log files from application even with administrator privileges.

My application manifest file have this line:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

and i run my application with "Run as Administrator".

How can my application have "System" privileges or is there any way to accomplish this.

There are lots of applications that can alter with system files when they are run with admin rights.

Thanks..

Note: Owner of the files that i need to alter seems like "Local Service".

Comment: Does your admin user has full control to the folder(s) of the files you are trying to modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't *see* the files, I wonder if this is an x86 vs x64 thing; there is a lot of magic that happens with system folder redirection depending on whether your program is 32-bit or 64-bit. Whichever it is: try compiling it as "the other", and see if it works. For example, if your program is currently 32-bit, compile it explicitly for 64-bit.

Comment: That worked for me, thanks! Here are some details explaining my case fully: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector

Answer (score 1):

The .net framework has a helper class, which will return the real path of the different folders.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath(v=vs.110).aspx

If you want to delete some stuff of the system folder you would need to check if your system is running 64bit, and if yes if your "logs" folder is either in Environment.SpecialFolder.System or Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86